# gnuplot : writing out particular settings into a "header"

Tags: svg, parameters, header, gnuplot, settings

It would be handy to have gnuplot write particular settings to an output file, ideally in a .svg, because svg *appears* very well suited for that - so the image file and settings are all together - however, it appears this is not feasible directly in gnuplot.

Working within the wxt and svg terminals, and especially multiplot, I have been able to see how gnuplot might interface with the shell (for example):

`! ls ; pwd ; echo $0`, `print sin(pi)`, `show terminal`. Trouble happens though when trying usual redirection such as `> foo.txt` and such - even starting a separate `gnuplot` session by script just to get the parameters. In particular, I found this interesting :

`output is sent to STDOUT`

`print output is sent to '<stderr>'`

... though I'm not sure what to do with that.

I could use e.g. `! cat gnuplot.inp | grep terminal >> gnuplot.svg`, and dig into further `awk/sed` scripting, but before doing that it would help to know if I'm missing any small details in `gnuplot` first. Thanks.

PS a trivial question : why is the shell in `gnuplot` `sh`, when the plain-old linux terminal shell I am using is `bash` and `SHELL=/bin/bash`? I notice that `shell` drops the session into the shell from which `gnuplot` was executed - not sure if that will help the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 The usual way to save current settings to a file is the command `save "filename"`.  There is a script in the gnuplot repository called `gpsavediff` (it may or may not be included in your distro's gnuplot package) that compares the saved values to the default settings and keeps only the ones that changed. From a gnuplot session under linux a typical use would be

```
 ... do a bunch of stuff to make a plot ...
 save "| gpsavediff > myplot.gp"
 ... do a bunch more stuff ...
 # recover original plot
 reset session
 load "myplot.gp"
```

2. To write specific lines or text to a file is much simpler than you show. For instance

.

```
set print "session.log" append
print "# This plot looked good on the screen."
print "# At this point the view angles were ", GPVAL_VIEW_ROT_X, GPVAL_VIEW_ROT_Z
print "# I save a PostScript copy to foo.ps"
set term push
set term postscript color
set output "foo.ps"
replot
unset output
set term pop
...
```

3. When invoking a shell, gnuplot uses the libc library function `popen()`. The gory details of popen() are somewhat system dependent but you probably have a man page for it.

gpsavediff script [here](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/scripts/files/gpsavediff)